# How to change text color in HTML table with angularjs or jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have table:
order id,status

status value: (closed,canceled)
Value get from maria-db.

This result I want see in html page(table).

- closed:   color -- red
- canceled: color -- green

This my td:

```
<td>{{data.orderid}}</td>
<td>{{data.status}}</td>
```

I use angularjs, (php for connection).

I tried this:

```
$('.status:contains("closed")').css('color', 'red'); 
$('.status:contains("canceled")').css('color', 'green');
```

Comment: Cool. How have you tried to accomplish your goal? (We're not here to write code for you; we're here to help _you_ with _your_ code. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].)

Comment: Sorry,I try this code but is not working for me:

Comment: $('.status:contains("closed")').css('color', 'red');
$('.status:contains("canceled")').css('color', 'green');

Comment: Please show your relevant HTML also. And are you asking about jQuery or Angular? Which libraries are loaded?

Comment: I think better with Angular

Comment: There is no `status` class in the HTML you posted.

Comment: <td class = "status">{{data.status}}</td> You mean???

Comment: Question, with I pull data from the database. Is this suitable for JQUERY or better for PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can you angular expression for this

1. Make two style with name greenStyle and redStyle

   .greenStyle{
      color:green;
   }

   .redStyle{
      color:red;
   }
2. In your table add.

```html
<td>{{data.orderid}}</td>
<td class="{{data.status=='closed'?'redStyle':'greenStyle'}}">{{data.status}}</td>
```